# How to get the values of Pandas Series at previous business date at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a pandas time-series as follows:

```
2012-01-02 17:16:00    0
2012-01-02 17:17:00    1
2012-01-03 17:16:00    2
2012-01-03 17:17:00    3
2012-01-03 17:18:00    4
```

I would like to get the values of the series at last day and the same time. If the same time does not exist the values should be NaN. So in this example the output is going to be:

```
2012-01-02 17:16:00    NA
2012-01-02 17:17:00    NA
2012-01-03 17:16:00    0
2012-01-03 17:17:00    1
2012-01-03 17:18:00    NA
```

The value corresponding to `2012-01-03 17:18:00`  is `NA` because its time (i.e `17:18`) does not exist in the previous day (i.e. `2012-01-02`)
Is there a way to do that in pandas?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reindex` on an index that subtracts a business day, then add one back to the index after.

```
import pandas as pd

s = s.reindex(s.index - pd.offsets.BDay())  # NaN if no obs 1 BDay prior, else match
s.index = s.index + pd.offsets.BDay()       

#2012-01-02 17:16:00    NaN
#2012-01-02 17:17:00    NaN
#2012-01-03 17:16:00    0.0
#2012-01-03 17:17:00    1.0
#2012-01-03 17:18:00    NaN
#dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so via `merge`:

```
(df.merge(df.assign(date=df['date']
                         .add(pd.offsets.BDay())
                   ),
          on='date',
          how='left',
          suffixes=['','_new'])
)
```

Output:

```
                 date  value  value_new
0 2012-01-02 17:16:00      0        NaN
1 2012-01-02 17:17:00      1        NaN
2 2012-01-03 17:16:00      2        0.0
3 2012-01-03 17:17:00      3        1.0
4 2012-01-03 17:18:00      4        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can also loop thru the dataframe and check